# Notify when programs access path only via specific symlink

Tags: inotify

My HDD mountpoint was at /mnt/old, now I changed it to /mnt/new

So for seamless transition now /mnt/old is a symlink to /mnt/new.

Gradually I want all the programs to use the new mountpoint.
How can I monitor what programs access the old path (currently symlink)?

fanotify doesn't work, it resolves the final path, so monitors /mnt/new.

Comment: fanotify_mark(2) tells about a flag FAN_MARK_DONT_FOLLOW to not follow symlinks. Maybe the tool you are using could benefit from this?

Comment: seems like it doesn't register any events then (working with `/mnt/old`, if I specify `/mnt/old/` then it's like before)

Comment: Does it work if you make `/mnt/old` a bind mount instead of a symlink to `/mnt/new`? Or export `/mnt/new` via nfs and mount it from the same machine on `/mnt/old`? (I'm not able to test any of those right now)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of Brendan Gregg's [perf-tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools), namely [opensnoop](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-25/opensnoop-for-linux.html), which is an *ftrace* script to monitor for files of a given name (a regular expression) being opened. For an `ls` command you would get output something like

```
$ sudo opensnoop /mnt/old
COMM             PID      FD FILE
ls               9263    0x3 /mnt/old
```

There are many other remarkable performance analysis tools based on Linux perf and ftrace in the set.